# Excel VBA Run-time error '424': Object Required when trying to copy TextBox

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I'm attempting to copy the contents of a text box from one `workbook` to another.  I have no problem copying cell values from the first `workbook` to the 2nd, but I get an `object required` error when I attempt to copy the text box.  This `macro` is being run from the workbook containing the data I want copied.  Using `Excel 2007` Code:

```
Sub UploadData()
    Dim xlo As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    Set xlw = xlo.Workbooks.Open("c:\myworkbook.xlsx")
    xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Range("d4").Value 'Copy cell content (this works fine)
    xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2) = TextBox1.Text 'This gives me the object required error
    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close
    Set xlo = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You tried with the full Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.TextBox1? Can you check if the ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet isn't xlw? If this is the case, you just have to set an object for your active document before opening another.

Comment: try this `...= activesheet.TextBox1.Object.value` or `.Text` property at the end should work too

Comment: I get an 'object doesn't support this property or method' with either of your solutions dnLL & KazJaw

Comment: But did you check what ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet are referring to? Seems like it refers to `xlw` (*c:\myworkbook.xlsx*) and not the document where is located `TextBox1`.

Comment: test also shorter option `...= Activesheet.TextBox1.Text` It's important to precede user controls with sheet object. However, if it doesn't work could you make a screen shot of your TextBox and add a link to that picture here?

Comment: Activesheet.TextBox1.Text gives the same error
It would appear that activesheet is referring to the destination workbook anyways

Comment: Which means you need to add a reference objet to the right workbook. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your macro is that once you have opened your destination *Workbook* (`xlw` in your code sample), it is set as the *ActiveWorkbook* object and you get an error because *TextBox1* doesn't exist in that specific *Workbook*. To resolve this issue, you could define a reference object to your actual *Workbook* before opening the other one.

```vb
Sub UploadData()
    Dim xlo As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    Dim myWb as Excel.Workbook

    Set myWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlw = xlo.Workbooks.Open("c:\myworkbook.xlsx")
    xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = myWb.ActiveSheet.Range("d4").Value
    xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2) = myWb.ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text

    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close
    Set xlo = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you prefer, you could also use `myWb.Activate` to put back your main *Workbook* as active. It will also work if you do it with a *Worksheet* object. Using one or another mostly depends on what you want to do (if there are multiple sheets, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that this is happening could be because `TextBox1` is scoping to the VBA module and its associated sheet, while Range is scoping to the "Active Sheet".

**EDIT**

It looks like you may be able to use the [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function to pull the textbox from the workbook.

Comment: Any idea how I can scope textbox1 to the active sheet?  I don't believe I can use ActiveSheet.TextBox1

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @dnLL Why?  It is an answer, not a comment or question.  It's not as thorough as your answer, but it is an answer [by definition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer).

Comment: I guess you are referring to the 8th definition. I still don't think that 2 sentences starting with "I think" and "you may be" is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line

```
 xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2) = TextBox1.Text
```

You have the textbox defined at some other location which you are not using here. Excel is unable to find the textbox object in the current sheet while this textbox was defined in xlw.

Hence replace this with

```
 xlo.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2) = worksheets("xlw").TextBox1.Text
```