# VBA Moving and Resizing charts

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm getting a runtime error 424 on debug that an object is required.
Is there a way to rewrite the code? I'm getting the error on the line: 
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Left

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$R$12")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Height = 450
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Width = 950
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLineDropLine)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Top = Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Top
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by trying out something I found here: [Excel VBA Run-time error '424': Object Required when trying to copy TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084686/excel-vba-run-time-error-424-object-required-when-trying-to-copy-textbox)

I changed the reference of 'Sheet1' to 'ActiveSheet' and it worked!

Thanks all